# uwp ListViewBase.ContainerFromIndex returns null

Tags: uwp

I am using the following code to locate an item in the ListView.

```
    public static bool ScrollToIndex(this ListViewBase listViewBase, int index)
    {
        if (listViewBase == null) return false;
        int count = listViewBase.Items.Count;
        if (index < 0 || index >= count) return false;
        if (listViewBase.ContainerFromIndex(index) is ListViewItem item)
        {
            item.Locate();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

It works when there is only a few items in the list. However, when the ListView has a lot of items in it, `ContainerFromIndex` keeps returning null for the items that are not visible. Only when I scroll to a position that is around the desired index, I can locate the Item expectedly.

I guess it might be the problem that the desired `LitsViewItem` is not loaded yet, so I tried to load more items by using `LoadMoreItemsAsync` in a loop.

```
public static async Task<bool> ScrollToIndexAsync(this ListViewBase listViewBase, int index)
{
    if (listViewBase == null) return false;
    int count = listViewBase.Items.Count;
    if (index < 0 || index >= count) return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (listViewBase.ContainerFromIndex(index) is ListViewItem item)
        {
            item.Locate();
            return true;
        }
        await listViewBase.LoadMoreItemsAsync();
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
    return false;
}
```

However, the code just directly aborted after `LoadMoreItemsAsync`. The code after that is not executed.

What should I do? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to ChatGPT, my problem is resolved! Just need another way to load the desired item instead of using `LoadMoreItemsAsync`. I have made minor modifications to ChatGPT's answer.

```
public static async Task<bool> ScrollToIndexAsync(this ListViewBase listViewBase, int index)
{
    if (listViewBase == null) return false;
    int count = listViewBase.Items.Count;
    if (index < 0 || index >= count) return false;
    if (listViewBase.ContainerFromIndex(index) is ListViewItem item)
    {
        // for better animation
        item.Locate();
        return true;
    }
    // Make sure the desired item is loaded
    await listViewBase.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        listViewBase.ScrollIntoView(listViewBase.Items[index], ScrollIntoViewAlignment.Default);
    });
    int tryLoadCount = 50;
    // keep waiting for the scrolling to finish
    // not using while loop here just in case of a dead while loop
    for (int i = 0; i < tryLoadCount; i++)
    {
        if (listViewBase.ContainerFromIndex(index) == null)
        {
            // delay a while and wait for the item to load
            await Task.Delay(100);
        } 
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    Debug.WriteLine("poor man")
    return false;
}
```